# Cordova / Telerik: stop location to enter the UIBackgroundModes array info.plist

Tags: ios, cordova, telerik, cordova-plugins

For an app I need the cordova Geolocation plugin. I don't need it to run in the background however. Though when building the app using Telerik/Cordova the plist will get the location service in the UIBackgroundModes.

I would like to prevent this from happening, but can't find a way to do so in the config.xml. I did find this:

```
<preference name="EnableLocation" value="false" />
```

however it seems deprecated so the 'location' service still ends up in my Info.plist.

Apple rejected my app because of two reasons:

```
Apps that declare support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file must have features that require persistent location. 
Please revise your app to include features that require the persistent use of real-time location updates while the app is in the background
```

and

```
If your app does not require persistent real-time location updates, please remove the "location" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.
```

I would like to do the last one, however I need to know how to prevent Cordova to add this to my plist when bulding the app.

Does anybody know a solution for this?
I cant remove it by hand, since I am working on a windows machine, I can't upload the .ipa file to iTunes connect

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: in Telerik (and probably somewhere in cordova) you can set the Background Mode. Location will be added to the Info.plist if you check the Background Mode: Location.

For an example see the image:

[image]